# MATLAB R2012a Installation Issue

Tags: 12.04, installation, 64-bit, matlab

I activated my student version of MATLAB R2012a on the Mathworks website with my original host ID (my Mac address).

For some reason MATLAB thinks that my host ID is 0000..0 (sequence of zeros) when I open MATLAB.

It exits with an error saying that this version of MATLAB is registered with some other host ID other than your computer's host id (00000000).

Its true because my hostid is not a sequence of zeros.

What do I do?

I installed MATLAB Student Version on my Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit OS. I installed ia32-libs too.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, I'm afraid. But I thought I'd say that in the meantime 'til someone gives you an answer that helps you may wish to download and install GNU Octave which has an almost identical syntax to MATLAB and is free. To obtain it just look it up in the Software Centre and install it. If you'd like a more user-friendly GUI (instead of a command-line  -- GNU Octave's default) for it install QtOctave via the software centre.

Answer (score 1):

switching to **eth0** helped me fix this installation. I think it only accepts eth0 as the network interface.

Comment: That's because every network interface has it's own mac adress, I guess you used the mac adress from eth0 to sign up.